# Meteor localhost, can't access local collection via console

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteorite

Doing the following it works fine:

```
$ mrt create testapp
$ cd testapp
$ mkdir local
$ cd local
$ mkdir collections
$ touch test.js
```

In test.js, I add:

```
Test = new Meteor.Collection('test');
```

Then I start Meteor:

```
$ meteor
```

Opening a new console tab, I start Mongo:

```
$ meteor mongo
```

I insert an entry:

```
$ db.test.insert({ Title: "This is a test" });
```

I open my browser on localhost and can use the console to see this:

```
test.findOne();
```

Okay so this works, as it's supposed to. However, I have a project I'm working on, that I've been working on for a couple of days. I cannot figure out what's causing the issue but I cannot access the collections via the console.

```
Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
```

I insert a test post with mongo console, and can retrieve it with mongo console, but in the browser I get:

```
Posts.findOne();
-- undefined
```

I've been digging and can't figure out what I could have possibly done to cause this to not work. I did initially launch this app from localhost, but with a remote DB hosted on MongoHQ. But I deleted the DB folder inside local, reset the app. Reset mongo. I created a new folder and copied the essential files over so meteor would essentially run for the first time. I can't figure out the problem.

:(

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: So I'm getting the intellisense in console so it is seeing the "Posts" variable. I'm gathering there's a syncing issue with the local DB and minimongo?

Comment: In your app, did you call `new Meteor.Collection...` from the console or did you put it in a shared directory like at the top of your question? Is `autopublish` on (or did you remove it)?

Comment: Hi David. In my app I'm calling new Meteor.Collection inside "client/collections/posts.js" I removed autopublish and added it back just to be sure, and it said:  Package iron-router has been ignored because it has been manually installed in /packages while installing. Does this have anything to do with it?

Comment: I don't know about the IR package error, but you have to define the collection in a way that **both** the client and the server can see it. If the server doesn't have the collection definition, then it can't write to the database on behalf of the client.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot. You're right, again. Haha. I misread the tutorial and placed collections inside of client, when it wasn't supposed to be. I'll go dig a hole for myself now. Thank you David. If you'll post this as an answer I'll accept it. I just can't believe I wasted this time and SO space for a wrongly placed directory.

Comment: Yeah, I know the feeling - sometimes it's just one simple fix. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the collection in a way that both the client and the server can see it. If the server doesn't have the collection definition, then it can't write to the database on behalf of the client. I'd recommend placing it a file like `collections/posts.js`.